# Comparar um inteiro digitado com cada valor do enum

Tags: java, enums

Olá.

Eu quero verificar se a opção que o usuário digitou corresponde a uma opção no menu. Estou usando o enum para mostrar as opções e o usuário digita um número correspondente. Mas não consigo.  Vejamos o enum do menu e a classe que estou testando.

```
package dominio;  

public enum EnumMenuInicial {  

    CADASTRAR(1), PESQUISAR(2), EXCLUIR(3);  

    public final int OPCAO;  

    private EnumMenuInicial(int opcaoEscolhida) {  
        EnumMenuInicial.OPCAO = opcaoEscolhida;  
    }  

} 

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Scanner;  
import dominio.EnumMenuInicial;  

public class Clinica {  

    private static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);  
    private static ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        Clinica.exibirMenuInicial();  
        int opcao = Clinica.readInt();  

}  

    private static boolean cadastrar() {  
        System.out.println("Informe o nome");  
        String nome = entrada.nextLine();  

        System.out.println("Informe CPF");  
        int cpf = Clinica.readInt();  

        System.out.println("Informe telefone");  
        int telefone = Clinica.readInt();  

        System.out.println("Informe o estado");  
        String estado = entrada.nextLine();  

        System.out.println("Informe a cidade");  
        String cidade = entrada.nextLine();  

        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nome, cpf, telefone, estado, cidade);  

        boolean inserido = Clinica.clientes.add(cliente);  

        return inserido;  
    }  

//limpar buffer  
    private static int readInt() {  
        int numero = entrada.nextInt();  
        entrada.nextLine();  
        return numero;  
    }  

    private static void exibirMenuInicial() {  
        int i = 1;  

        System.out.println("Escolha uma opção:");  

        for (EnumMenuInicial opcao : EnumMenuInicial.values()) {  
            System.out.println(i + ": " + opcao.toString());  
            i++;  
        }  
    }  

    private static boolean validarOpcao(int opcaoEscolhida) {  
        int i = 0;  
        for (EnumMenuInicial opcao : EnumMenuInicial.values()) {  
            if (opcaoEscolhida == OPCAO) {  

    return true;            }  
        }  
}  

    return false;  
    }  

}
```

Na linha:

```
            if (opcaoEscolhida == OPCAO) {
```

dar o erro:

> OPCAO cannot be resolved to a variable    Clinica.java    /clinica/src    line 61 Java Problem >

se eu mudar para:

```
            if (opcaoEscolhida == EnumMenuInicial.OPCAO) {
```

Dá o erro:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field EnumMenuInicial.OPCAO  Clinica.java    /clinica/src    line 63 Java Problem  >

Como posso corrigir esta situação?

Comment: Em `if (opcaoEscolhida == OPCAO)` o correto seria `if (opcaoEscolhida == opcao.OPCAO)`.

Comment: @Caffé Valeu, corrigi.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa seria verificar todas as opções do enum usando um `foreach`:

```
public enum EnumMenuInicial {

    CADASTRAR(1), PESQUISAR(2), EXCLUIR(3);

    private int opcao;

    private EnumMenuInicial(int opcaoEscolhida) {
        opcao = opcaoEscolhida;
    }

    public int getOpcao() {
        return opcao;
    }

    public static EnumMenuInicial procurarOpcao(int id) {
        for(EnumMenuInicial e : values()) {
            if (e.getOpcao() == id)
                return e;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Assim, basta verificar usando esse metodo `procurarOpcao` passando a entrada do usuário:

```
EnumMenuInicial opcao = EnumMenuInicial.prucurarOpcao(Integer.parseInt("3"));
if (opcao != null) {
    //Opcao é válida...
} else {
    //Opcao inválida...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrigi. Onde tem:

```
        if (opcaoEscolhida == OPCAO) {
```

Coloquei:

```
        if (opcaoEscolhida == opcao.OPCAO) {
```

O código apresentado na dúvida, agora corrigido, ficou:

package dominio;

public enum EnumMenuInicial {

```
CADASTRAR(1), PESQUISAR(2), EXCLUIR(3);  

public final int OPCAO;  

private EnumMenuInicial(int opcaoEscolhida) {  
    EnumMenuInicial.OPCAO = opcaoEscolhida;  
}
```

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import dominio.EnumMenuInicial;

public class Clinica {

```
private static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);  
private static ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();  

public static void main(String args[]) {  
    Clinica.exibirMenuInicial();  
    int opcao = Clinica.readInt();
```

}

```
private static boolean cadastrar() {  
    System.out.println("Informe o nome");  
    String nome = entrada.nextLine();  

    System.out.println("Informe CPF");  
    int cpf = Clinica.readInt();  

    System.out.println("Informe telefone");  
    int telefone = Clinica.readInt();  

    System.out.println("Informe o estado");  
    String estado = entrada.nextLine();  

    System.out.println("Informe a cidade");  
    String cidade = entrada.nextLine();  

    Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nome, cpf, telefone, estado, cidade);  

    boolean inserido = Clinica.clientes.add(cliente);  

    return inserido;  
}
```

//limpar buffer
    private static int readInt() {
        int numero = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine();
        return numero;
    }

```
private static void exibirMenuInicial() {  
    int i = 1;  

    System.out.println("Escolha uma opção:");  

    for (EnumMenuInicial opcao : EnumMenuInicial.values()) {  
        System.out.println(i + ": " + opcao.toString());  
        i++;  
    }  
}  

private static boolean validarOpcao(int opcaoEscolhida) {  
    int i = 0;  
    for (EnumMenuInicial opcao : EnumMenuInicial.values()) {  
        if (opcaoEscolhida == opcao.OPCAO) {  

return true;            }  
    }
```

}

```
return false;  
}
```

}

Comment: Isso aqui: *EnumMenuInicial.OPCAO = opcaoEscolhida;* também tá esquisito. Nem sei como pode estar funcionando. O correto seria apenas *OPCAO = opcaoEscolhida;* ou *this.OPCAO = opcaoEscolhida;*, já que *OPCAO* é uma variável da instância e não da classe.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sugiro alterar o seu `enum,` você está utilizando a referência de classe para alterar uma variável `final` o que não é correto, utilize o `this`para isto.
2. Adicione métodos no seu `enum` para facilitar o seu trabalho.

Sugiro a seguinte alteração, existem outras soluções, mas esta pode ser aplicada.

**Classe enum**

```
public enum EnumMenuInicial {  

    CADASTRAR(1), PESQUISAR(2), EXCLUIR(3);  

    public final int OPCAO;  

    private EnumMenuInicial(int opcaoEscolhida) {  
        this.OPCAO = opcaoEscolhida;  
    }  

    public static EnumMenuInicial getOpcao(int opcao){
        switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                return CADASTRAR;
           case 2:
                return PESQUISAR;
            case 3:
                return EXCLUIR;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

}
```

**Validar Opção**

```
private static boolean validarOpcao(int opcaoEscolhida) {
    try {
        EnumMenuInicial opcao = EnumMenuInicial.getOpcao(opcaoEscolhida);
        System.out.println("Opcao Escolhida: " + opcao);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println("Opcao Inválida: " + opcaoEscolhida);
        return false;
    }
}
```